# How to pass value to hidden field based on two Yes/No radio selections

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

We have a form with two Yes/No questions:

Question 1: Yes/No

Question 2: Yes/No

We'd like to pass a value to the hidden field "leadSource" based on the following four scenarios when the form is submitted:

1. Q1=Yes; Q2=Yes hidden; field name "leadSource" value = "A"
2. Q1=Yes; Q2=No hidden; field name "leadSource" value = "B"
3. Q1=No; Q2=Yes hidden; field name "leadSource" value = "C"
4. Q1=No; Q2=No hidden; field name "leadSource" value = "D"

How can I code the four different scenarios in jQuery, so that it passes the value to a hidden field?

```
    <form id="addLeadSource">
    <input type="hidden" name="leadSource" value="" id="leadSource" class="leadSource">

    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="labeltext">Would you say yes or no to this first question?</label><br>
     <div class="form-check-inline">

      <label class="Q1YesLabel">
      <span class="radiotextsty">Yes</span>
      <input type="radio" class="Q1Yes" name="Q1" value="Yes" id="Q1Yes" required>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>        
      <label class="Q1NoLabel"><span class="radiotextsty">No</span>
      <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="No" id="Q1No" required>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group" id="Q2">
     <label class="labeltext">How about this one?</label><br>
     <div class="form-check-inline">

     <label class="Q2YesLabel"><span class="radiotextsty">Yes</span>
     <input type="radio" class="directly_sourced" name="directly_sourced" value="Yes" required>
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
     </label>        
     <label class="Q2NoLabel"><span class="radiotextsty">No</span>
     <input type="radio" name="directly_sourced" value="No" required>
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
     </label>
     </div>
     </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

     </form>

    $(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'Q1No') {
            $('#Q2').show();           
       }
   });
        });

      $(document).ready(function() {
             $('input.ZoomInfo_sourced[type=radio]').change(function() { //change event by class
              if (this.value == 'Yes - ZoomInfo Sourced') {
                  $(this.ClassName[type=hidden]).val("Zoominfo - Seller");
                  alert("Zoominfo - Seller");
              }
              else if (this.value == '1') {
                 $(this.source[type=hidden]).val("Yes");
              }
          });
        });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addLeadSource").submit(function(event){
  var source = document.getElementById("leadSource").innerText;
    alert(source);
    });
});
```

I've got a fiddle started here: https://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/mqzdvyha/

Comment: did the answer below solve your question?

Comment: It helped me come up with the solution. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with that worked for me:

```
    $("#theForm").submit(function(event) {

      if ($('#Q1Yes').is(':checked') && $('#Q2Yes').is(':checked')) {
        $("#source").val("Scenario 1 and 2");

      } else if ($('#Q1Yes').is(':checked') && $('#Q2No').is(':checked')) {
        $("#source").val("Scenario 1 and 2");

      } else if ($('#Q1No').is(':checked') && $('#Q2Yes').is(':checked')) {
        $("#source").val("Scenario 3");

      } else {
        $("#source").val("Scenario 4");
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways to write this, but I think the logic is pretty easy to follow this way.

```js
  function testme() {
     if ($('[name="Q1"]:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
        console.log('q1 is yes');
        if ($('[name="directly_sourced"]:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
           console.log('q2 is yes');
           return 'A';
        } else {
           console.log('q2 is no');
           return 'B';
        }
     } else {
        console.log('q1 is no');
        if ($('[name="directly_sourced"]:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
           console.log('q2 is yes');
           return 'C';
        } else {
           console.log('q2 is no');
           return 'D';
        }       
     }
  }
```

Basically just branching if else statements that follow the layout of your question pretty well.  It does assume a non answer is a no if that matters...  Using this function you could have `$('#leadSource').val(testme());` when the form is submitted